# I'm trying to get location on android device But it crashes immediately after execution

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I'm trying to get location on android device the code is as follows:

```
private void openLocation() {
    lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria c = new Criteria();
    pro = lm.getBestProvider(c,false);
    Location l = lm.getLastKnownLocation(pro);

    if (l != null) {
        Toast.makeText(WebActivity.this, "Longitude : "+String.valueOf(l.getLongitude())+", Latitude : "+String.valueOf(l.getLatitude()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(WebActivity.this,"loc object is null",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    mgac = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
}
```

but it crashes when executed. What's wrong in the code, or please give me a working code that give me location to string and I want to send the data to another url using get/post request and this request should run in background.

Comment: if it crashes first see is it consoling some error/exception in console, if yes what is it?

Comment: Use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help u,

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

            try {

                URL url = new URL(url);
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url
                        .openConnection();
                conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
                conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                // Starts the query

                conn.connect();
                InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream();

                String data = convertStreamToString(stream);

                // u can read data here
                stream.close();


            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    });

    thread.start();
```

& the convertStreamToString is,

```
static String convertStreamToString(java.io.InputStream is) {
        java.util.Scanner s = new java.util.Scanner(is).useDelimiter("\\A");
        return s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "";
    }
```

this can help you in sending the some request to server in background but
for getting location I'm not very sure.

Comment: Please explain what this has to do with the question.

Comment: he wants to send These data to some url using get/post request and this request should run in background and I think this is a solution for that @Commons sir.

Comment: @AkhileshKumar you are right but it would be batter if you can answer my first question also